# How to calculate the weight and value in lightgbm?

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, lightgbm

We can use `tree_to_dataframe` or `lgb.create_tree_digraph` to display the structure of lightgbm model. The internal node and leaf node both have `weight` and `value`.

The document says:

> `value` : float64, predicted value for this leaf node, multiplied by the learning rate.
>
> `weight` : float64 or int64, sum of hessian (second-order derivative of objective), summed over observations that fall in this node..
> How are the two values calculated?

we know that, in binary logloss:
[image: $$ \begin{aligned} G &= \hat{y}-y \ H &= \hat{y}(1-\hat{y}) \end{aligned} $$]

1. The $H$ will not be $0$ as we have a `base value` before the first tree is created,  but why the weight in each tree's root node is $0$ in the following example?
2. How is the internal node's `value` calculated?

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn

X, y = sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(random_state=1, n_estimators=2,
                           max_depth=1,
                           min_child_weight=15,
                           objective='binary'
                          )
model.fit(X, y)
model.booster_.trees_to_dataframe()
```

|  | tree_index | node_depth | node_index | left_child | right_child | parent_index | split_feature | split_gain | threshold | decision_type | missing_direction | missing_type | value | weight | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0-S0 | 0-L0 | 0-L1 |  | Column_23 | 392.505 | 868.2 | <= | left | None | 0.52115 | 0 | 569 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 0-L0 |  |  | 0-S0 |  | nan | nan |  |  |  | 0.641339 | 89.2982 | 382 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 0-L1 |  |  | 0-S0 |  | nan | nan |  |  |  | 0.275629 | 43.7141 | 187 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1-S0 | 1-L0 | 1-L1 |  | Column_7 | 327.362 | 0.05142 | <= | left | None | 0 | 0 | 569 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 1-L0 |  |  | 1-S0 |  | nan | nan |  |  |  | 0.128938 | 79.2656 | 349 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 1-L1 |  |  | 1-S0 |  | nan | nan |  |  |  | -0.19224 | 52.9234 | 220 |

```py
lgb.create_tree_digraph(model, tree_index=0, show_info=['split_gain', 'internal_value', 'internal_count',
                                                        'internal_weight', 'leaf_count', 'leaf_weight', 'data_percentage'])
```

[image]

```py
lgb.create_tree_digraph(model, tree_index=0, show_info=['split_gain', 'internal_value', 'internal_count',
                                                        'internal_weight', 'leaf_count', 'leaf_weight', 'data_percentage'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just quick question: Have you studied how a a normal Extreme Gradient Tree works maybe from the scikitlearn library?

You are using LightGBM, which is a fanstastic algorithm but advanced. Maybe go first with the general concepts, the math behind the algorithm, papers... and then you would be able to answer yourself.

The article referent to Light GBM:

https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2017/file/6449f44a102fde848669bdd9eb6b76fa-Paper.pdf

The repo code in github, you can explore everything you need:

https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM

And the documentation:

https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I've read this paper in fact, but I am not familiar with C/C++ code. I am wondering why the sum of hessian in the root node is 0, as this node have all samples and hessian calculated by y(1-y) which is not  zero, can you point out which part should I notice?

Comment: First of all, you should look with this you have familiarity. For instance, if you had look one second more on the github, you could end up with: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/python-package/lightgbm   max_depth = 1. So that means that the trees split one time. Before and after you calculate the H right?. Now my question is, it's always 0, or it is just for this two columns? If it's only particular i would say is 0 because that could be y=y_hat -> H=y*(y-y)=0, trivial case. Could be  involved some rounding... Etc